# Firebase realtime database data persistence #AskFirebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, data-persistence

I've implemented Firebase Realtime Database in my android app with data persistency. My expectation was that, as data persistence was active, each time my app was open, Firebase would not check for database updates.

Anyway, according to my tests, I noticed that, everytime I open my app,  some tests and, according to what I noticed, data usage increased near 10KB. But considering that my app has a service which must check a data in each second, I cannot make device consume internet to check data 3600 times every hour: I'll have to save this specific data locally.

So, that's my question: when data persistence is active in realtime database, why everytime my app is open, data usage is increased in something like 10KB?